# Using jquery clone function only one data is saved to database Django

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, database

if there are two forms then only the value of last form is registered on the data base if clicked on submit button.

The thing that i want is to dynamically add forms according to the integer provided by the user (eg. If the user wants 3 rooms then 3 forms are to be added dynamically) and the data in the form is to be added on the database

NOTE: multiple Forms are generated by clone function from jquery and forms are generated too but they are not saved in database....

HTML CODE

```
<form id = "mainForm" method ="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div id="first-group" class = "new">
    <div id="bookform">
        <n class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></n>
        <input name="name" type="text" id="input" placeholder="Name" name="name" required/>
    </div>
    <div id="bookform">
        <n class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></n>
        <select  name="nationality"  id="nation" style="width: 95%; border: none;" required>
            <option data-display="">Nationality</option>
            <option value="afghan">Afghan</option>
            <option value="albanian">Albanian</option>
            <option value="algerian">Algerian</option>
            <option value="american">American</option>
            <option value="andorran">Andorran</option>
            <option value="angolan">Angolan</option>
            <option value="antiguans">Antiguans</option>
            <option value="argentinean">Argentinean</option>
            <option value="armenian">Armenian</option>
            <option value="australian">Australian</option>
            <option value="austrian">Austrian</option>
            <option value="azerbaijani">Azerbaijani</option>
            <option value="bahamian">Bahamian</option>
            <option value="bahraini">Bahraini</option>
            <option value="bangladeshi">Bangladeshi</option>
            <option value="barbadian">Barbadian</option>
            <option value="barbudans">Barbudans</option>
            <option value="batswana">Batswana</option>
            <option value="belarusian">Belarusian</option>
            <option value="belgian">Belgian</option>
            <option value="belizean">Belizean</option>
            <option value="beninese">Beninese</option>
            <option value="bhutanese">Bhutanese</option>
            <option value="bolivian">Bolivian</option>
            <option value="bosnian">Bosnian</option>
            <option value="brazilian">Brazilian</option>
            <option value="british">British</option>
            <option value="bruneian">Bruneian</option>
            <option value="bulgarian">Bulgarian</option>
            <option value="burkinabe">Burkinabe</option>
            <option value="burmese">Burmese</option>
            <option value="burundian">Burundian</option>
            <option value="cambodian">Cambodian</option>
            <option value="cameroonian">Cameroonian</option>
            <option value="canadian">Canadian</option>
            <option value="cape verdean">Cape Verdean</option>
            <option value="central african">Central African</option>
            <option value="chadian">Chadian</option>
            <option value="chilean">Chilean</option>
            <option value="chinese">Chinese</option>
            <option value="colombian">Colombian</option>
            <option value="comoran">Comoran</option>
            <option value="congolese">Congolese</option>
            <option value="costa rican">Costa Rican</option>
            <option value="croatian">Croatian</option>
            <option value="cuban">Cuban</option>
            <option value="cypriot">Cypriot</option>
            <option value="czech">Czech</option>
            <option value="danish">Danish</option>
            <option value="djibouti">Djibouti</option>
            <option value="dominican">Dominican</option>
            <option value="dutch">Dutch</option>
            <option value="east timorese">East Timorese</option>
            <option value="ecuadorean">Ecuadorean</option>
            <option value="egyptian">Egyptian</option>
            <option value="emirian">Emirian</option>
            <option value="equatorial guinean">Equatorial Guinean</option>
            <option value="eritrean">Eritrean</option>
            <option value="estonian">Estonian</option>
            <option value="ethiopian">Ethiopian</option>
            <option value="fijian">Fijian</option>
            <option value="filipino">Filipino</option>
            <option value="finnish">Finnish</option>
            <option value="french">French</option>
            <option value="gabonese">Gabonese</option>
            <option value="gambian">Gambian</option>
            <option value="georgian">Georgian</option>
            <option value="german">German</option>
            <option value="ghanaian">Ghanaian</option>
            <option value="greek">Greek</option>
            <option value="grenadian">Grenadian</option>
            <option value="guatemalan">Guatemalan</option>
            <option value="guinea-bissauan">Guinea-Bissauan</option>
            <option value="guinean">Guinean</option>
            <option value="guyanese">Guyanese</option>
            <option value="haitian">Haitian</option>
            <option value="herzegovinian">Herzegovinian</option>
            <option value="honduran">Honduran</option>
            <option value="hungarian">Hungarian</option>
            <option value="icelander">Icelander</option>
            <option value="indian">Indian</option>
            <option value="indonesian">Indonesian</option>
            <option value="iranian">Iranian</option>
            <option value="iraqi">Iraqi</option>
            <option value="irish">Irish</option>
            <option value="israeli">Israeli</option>
            <option value="italian">Italian</option>
            <option value="ivorian">Ivorian</option>
            <option value="jamaican">Jamaican</option>
            <option value="japanese">Japanese</option>
            <option value="jordanian">Jordanian</option>
            <option value="kazakhstani">Kazakhstani</option>
            <option value="kenyan">Kenyan</option>
            <option value="kittian and nevisian">Kittian and Nevisian</option>
            <option value="kuwaiti">Kuwaiti</option>
            <option value="kyrgyz">Kyrgyz</option>
            <option value="laotian">Laotian</option>
            <option value="latvian">Latvian</option>
            <option value="lebanese">Lebanese</option>
            <option value="liberian">Liberian</option>
            <option value="libyan">Libyan</option>
            <option value="liechtensteiner">Liechtensteiner</option>
            <option value="lithuanian">Lithuanian</option>
            <option value="luxembourger">Luxembourger</option>
            <option value="macedonian">Macedonian</option>
            <option value="malagasy">Malagasy</option>
            <option value="malawian">Malawian</option>
            <option value="malaysian">Malaysian</option>
            <option value="maldivan">Maldivan</option>
            <option value="malian">Malian</option>
            <option value="maltese">Maltese</option>
            <option value="marshallese">Marshallese</option>
            <option value="mauritanian">Mauritanian</option>
            <option value="mauritian">Mauritian</option>
            <option value="mexican">Mexican</option>
            <option value="micronesian">Micronesian</option>
            <option value="moldovan">Moldovan</option>
            <option value="monacan">Monacan</option>
            <option value="mongolian">Mongolian</option>
            <option value="moroccan">Moroccan</option>
            <option value="mosotho">Mosotho</option>
            <option value="motswana">Motswana</option>
            <option value="mozambican">Mozambican</option>
            <option value="namibian">Namibian</option>
            <option value="nauruan">Nauruan</option>
            <option value="nepalese">Nepalese</option>
            <option value="new zealander">New Zealander</option>
            <option value="ni-vanuatu">Ni-Vanuatu</option>
            <option value="nicaraguan">Nicaraguan</option>
            <option value="nigerien">Nigerien</option>
            <option value="north korean">North Korean</option>
            <option value="northern irish">Northern Irish</option>
            <option value="norwegian">Norwegian</option>
            <option value="omani">Omani</option>
            <option value="pakistani">Pakistani</option>
            <option value="palauan">Palauan</option>
            <option value="panamanian">Panamanian</option>
            <option value="papua new guinean">Papua New Guinean</option>
            <option value="paraguayan">Paraguayan</option>
            <option value="peruvian">Peruvian</option>
            <option value="polish">Polish</option>
            <option value="portuguese">Portuguese</option>
            <option value="qatari">Qatari</option>
            <option value="romanian">Romanian</option>
            <option value="russian">Russian</option>
            <option value="rwandan">Rwandan</option>
            <option value="saint lucian">Saint Lucian</option>
            <option value="salvadoran">Salvadoran</option>
            <option value="samoan">Samoan</option>
            <option value="san marinese">San Marinese</option>
            <option value="sao tomean">Sao Tomean</option>
            <option value="saudi">Saudi</option>
            <option value="scottish">Scottish</option>
            <option value="senegalese">Senegalese</option>
            <option value="serbian">Serbian</option>
            <option value="seychellois">Seychellois</option>
            <option value="sierra leonean">Sierra Leonean</option>
            <option value="singaporean">Singaporean</option>
            <option value="slovakian">Slovakian</option>
            <option value="slovenian">Slovenian</option>
            <option value="solomon islander">Solomon Islander</option>
            <option value="somali">Somali</option>
            <option value="south african">South African</option>
            <option value="south korean">South Korean</option>
            <option value="spanish">Spanish</option>
            <option value="sri lankan">Sri Lankan</option>
            <option value="sudanese">Sudanese</option>
            <option value="surinamer">Surinamer</option>
            <option value="swazi">Swazi</option>
            <option value="swedish">Swedish</option>
            <option value="swiss">Swiss</option>
            <option value="syrian">Syrian</option>
            <option value="taiwanese">Taiwanese</option>
            <option value="tajik">Tajik</option>
            <option value="tanzanian">Tanzanian</option>
            <option value="thai">Thai</option>
            <option value="togolese">Togolese</option>
            <option value="tongan">Tongan</option>
            <option value="trinidadian or tobagonian">Trinidadian or Tobagonian</option>
            <option value="tunisian">Tunisian</option>
            <option value="turkish">Turkish</option>
            <option value="tuvaluan">Tuvaluan</option>
            <option value="ugandan">Ugandan</option>
            <option value="ukrainian">Ukrainian</option>
            <option value="uruguayan">Uruguayan</option>
            <option value="uzbekistani">Uzbekistani</option>
            <option value="venezuelan">Venezuelan</option>
            <option value="vietnamese">Vietnamese</option>
            <option value="welsh">Welsh</option>
            <option value="yemenite">Yemenite</option>
            <option value="zambian">Zambian</option>
            <option value="zimbabwean">Zimbabwean</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="bookform">
        <n class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></n>
        <input name="address" type="text" id="input" placeholder="Address" name="address" required/>
    </div>
    <div id="bookform">
        <n class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></n>
        <input name="passport" type="text" id="input" placeholder="Passport Number" name="passport" required/>
    </div>
    <div id="bookform">
        <n class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></n>
        <input name="email" type="text" id="input" placeholder="E-mail Address" name="email" required/>
    </div>
    <div id="bookform">
        <n class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></n>
        <input  name="phnumber" type="text" id="input" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phnumber" required/>
    </div>
    <div id="ci">Arrival Date:</div>
    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker11">
        <input  name="checkin" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Arrival Date" onfocus="(this.type='datetime-local')" id="fdate1" required/>
    </div>
    <div id="ci">Depature Date:</div>
    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
        <input name="checkout" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Depature Date" onfocus="(this.type='datetime-local')" id="fdate2" required/>
    </div>
    <div id="bookform">
        <div id = "rooms">
        <n class="fa fa-bed" aria-hidden="true"></n>
        <select  name="roomtype" id="rooms" style="width: 95%; border: none;" required>
            <option data-display="" id="ai"></option>
            <option value="">Standard Room</option>
            <option value="">Deluxe Room</option>
            <option value="">Club Room</option>
            <option value="">Suites</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ci">Payment on Arrival</div>
</div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn theme_btn button_hover">submit
    </button>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT
Localstorage rooms contains integer value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
const lol = $(".new").clone();
rom = parseInt( localStorage.getItem('ROOMS'));
for(var i=1; i < rom; i++){
    $(".new").append(lol.clone());
}
```

})

models.py

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    passport = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phnumber = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    checkin = models.DateTimeField(max_length=20)
    checkout = models.DateTimeField(max_length=20)
    roomtype = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "room_book"
```

VIEWS.py

```
def form(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        booking = Booking()
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        address = request.POST.get('address')
        nationality = request.POST.get('nationality')
        passport = request.POST.get('passport')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        phnumber = request.POST.get('phnumber')
        checkin = request.POST.get('checkin')
        checkout = request.POST.get('checkout')
        roomtype = request.POST.get('roomtype')
        booking.name = name
        booking.address = address
        booking.nationality = nationality
        booking.passport = passport
        booking.email = email
        booking.phnumber = phnumber
        booking.checkin = checkin
        booking.checkout = checkout
        booking.roomtype = roomtype
        booking.save()

        send_mail(
            name,
            passport,
            'testproject1345@gmail.com',
            [email],
            fail_silently=False)
        return render(request, 'conBook.html', {'name': name, 'ranNum': ranNum})

    return render(request, 'form.html')
```

Comment: Why would you want the user for multiple rooms to fill out it's name, email and address multiple times too? I wouldn't recommend that considering user experience.

Comment: All the cloned forms have the same field names (eg. ` <input name="name"`), and sending multiple fields with the same name will always be sent as a single value only, the one which is last in the webpage.